# Python list comprehension on class

Tags: python, list-comprehension

take the following class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,boolean):
        bar = boolean
```

and let `foos` be a list of instances of `Foo`

I want to do the following in a list comprehension:

```
hold = []
for foo in foos:
    foo.added = "I was added in iteration"
    if foo.bar:
        hold.append(some_function(foo.bar))
    else:
        hold.append(some_other_function(foo.bar))
```

**note: this is not actually how it looks, I just needed to make an if and else**

So without the `foo.added` line, this is my solution:

```
[some_function(foo.bar) if foo.bar else some_other_function(foo.bar) for foo in foos]
```

**How can I also add an attribute in a list comprehension?**

## reason for this:

The code that I am running will be accessed so frequently that every fragment of a second of processing counts here. A list comprehension avoids the `append` line, and given the amount this is called, that could be very helpful

Comment: Just write it as loop. That's *much* clearer than any possible list comprehension.

Comment: but it is slightly less efficient and here every nano-second counts

Comment: If every nanosecond counts, you should be writing C. But I doubt that's the case. If you want to optimize, there are almost certainly better starting points (what exactly is hard to tell without knowing your whole code). Also, I'm not at all convinced that shoehorning this into a list comprehension will be faster - idiomatic usage is typically a bit faster than the equivalent loop, but you may have to add some complications (e.g. a function call) to make it work which could easily eat any speed advantage.

Comment: Donald Knuth says `...about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%` This is not in that 3%

Comment: haha fair enough, point made. Although the actual use of this is in serialization of something to be called thousands of times in a minute, I guess my original though just isn't worth it

Comment: Thousands of times per minute is nothing, try millions of times per 1/60th second ;-)

Comment: If you're looking for ways to improve speed, set up some test cases and play with the ```timeit``` module

Comment: XY problem.  The actual question seems to be "how do I make this code faster?" but the asked question is "how do I write this as a listcomp?", which may or may not be faster and is pretty unlikely to be the fastest.

Comment: @delnan yes that is much bigger, and I have one thing in that project that will be signaled at a similar frequency to that, this one is not one of those models

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for learning purpose, never use this is in real code. **A normal loop is a far better choice here**:

```
[some_function() if foo.bar else some_other_function() 
         for foo in foos if not setattr(foo, 'added',  "I was added in iteration")]
```

Comment: You should super bold that first line there

Comment: That is an interesting little hack that does work haha